# RedLaser driver's license scanner - calibrating for each state (iOS)

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, calibration

I'm using RedLaser's PDF214 scanner to pull data off the 2D barcode on the back of driver's licenses (iOS).

Issue: for each new state (or at least most), I have to recalibrate to work with that specific state's barcode.

Examples of differing barcodes:

Georgia: http://www.dds.ga.gov/docs/news/ga_d600_2dbarcodesheet_rev100112_v2after.pdf

Illinois: http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/departments/drivers/drivers_license/newdlflyer1.pdf

Any resources or suggestions on how to rapidly get this working for all states?  The current process is very manual and requires a license (or photo) of each state's barcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAMVA has documentation for entire US and you can recalibrate (implement) support for all states according to this document: http://www.aamva.org/DL-ID-Card-Design-Standard/

Disclaimer: I work for a company that has developed such commercial decoding API: https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-android/blob/master/DriversLicenseKeys.md